# know the Facebook and Twitter account linked to a YouTube channel

Tags: api, twitter, youtube, account

I would like to know what does Socialblade do to get the Facebook and twitter account linked to a YouTube channel. I can not find any help on the YouTube API.
Does anyone know?

Thank you for your help.